# Does the explicit formula for recurrence relation exist

Tags: recurrence-relations

Does an explicit formula exist for this recurrence relation? If so, what is it?

$ f(0) = 1 $

$ f(n) = \frac{n}{f(n-1)} $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n>0$ is even, then
$$
f(n)=\frac{2^{n-1}\cdot k!\cdot(k-1)!}{(n-1)!} 
$$
for $n=2k.$ For odd $n$, we have
$$
f(n)=\frac{n!}{2^{n-1}\cdot (k!)^2 } 
$$
for $n=2k+1$.

**Edit**: To obtain the result, one observes that 
$$
f(n)=\frac{n(n-2)(n-4)\ \dots}{(n-1)(n-3)\ \dots}\ ,
$$
the dots end in $1$ or $2$ depending on weather $n$ is odd or even. Then we merely collect the terms to arrive at the formula I described.

> Note that we can express $f$ using the [Double Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) notation, as mentioned in Mr. Milo's comment.

Comment: It might be helpful to the author to note that for even $n$ one has $2^{n}k!=n!!$ where $n!!$ is the double factorial $n(n-2)(n-4)\ldots$ and that $2^{n-1}(n-1)!/(k-1)!=(n-1)!!$, so even $n$ has $f(n)=\frac{n!!}{(n-1)!!}$. (Or to give some other explanation of how these identities are arrived at)

Comment: Ok, I'll edit accordingly.